# textbox value change event not getting fired jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-events

I am filling texbox value through ajax call. I want to change event get fired when the value gets filled.

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxExecute.aspx/GetCustInfoTeller',
    data: strRequest,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    context: document.body,
    type: 'POST',
    
    success: function (response) {
        var saResponse = response.d.split("|");
        $('#txtDateofBirth').val(saResponse[0]); // For this textbox change event gets fired    
    }
});
```

Code for change event handler:

```
$("#txtDateofBirth").bind('change', function () {
    alert('1');
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date($("#txtDateofBirth").val());
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    alert(age);
    if (age > 7) {
        $('#trMinor').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#trMinor').show();
    }
});
```

I am not getting alert when value is entered in `txtDateofBirth` through ajax.

Comment: Are you using an old version of jQuery (< 1.7)? If not, why don't you use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`?

Comment: Trigger the event, `$('#txtDateofBirth').val(saResponse[0]).change()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to trigger the event manually, it is only triggered automatically if the change was initiated by the user interface. Programmatically setting the value does not trigger the `change` event.

You can trigger an event with the [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) jQuery method:

```
$('#txtDateofBirth').val(saResponse[0]).trigger('change');
//or
$('#txtDateofBirth').val(saResponse[0]).change();
```